# How to read from a web page in Flask before rendering it?

Tags: flask

I would like to add conditional display of a what's new page after logon to my site based on the version of the page. To simplify changes I would like my code to read the version from the page itself so code changes will not be needed in the future - just HTML. I am not sure how to do this...

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
@bp.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login:()
    if login_user(user, password):
        return redirect( url_for('whats_new'))

def whats_new()
    # read version from header of whats_new.html 
    ver = get_version_from_webpage()
    if ver > 3 :
        return render ('whats_new.html')
    else:
        return redirect ('home.html')

def get_version_from_webpage():
    # THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK!
    # ??????????
    return ver
```

whats_new.html would contain the version number - perhaps in `<meta name="version" content="4"/>`

Any ideas how to get the version without visibly rendering the page first?

Comment: can you explain why you want to hardcode a version to a html file? i'm a bit ocnfused about your goal here

Comment: I want to avoid touching the code or the db every time the what's new page is updated and allow each user to hide( & not see again) that page when they have read it. Of course this can all be done in the db but I am trying to KISS  by 'simply' having a version in the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for anyone interested.
Using the requests library to get a page does not display it as it is Python not Flask.
The gotten response contains the whole page so it needs to be parsed to find the data we want. There is a library for that called BeautifulSoup.

Here is my working code

```
def get_pageversion(url):
    # retrieves content value of meta field  'version'
    # <meta name="version" content="4"/> would return 4.0
    try:
        ret = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(ret.text, features="html.parser")
        metas = soup.find_all('meta')
        version = float(next(iter([meta.attrs['content'] for meta in metas if meta.attrs.get('name') == 'version'])))
        return version
    except:
        return 0
```